# Is there a way to modify the storage backend used by a Django FileField?

Tags: django, django-models

I am saving some uploaded files with a Django FileField set to use DefaultStorage backend.  At some point after the file has been uploaded I'd like to *move* them to a different storage backend i.e. change the FileField's `storage` attribute (obv. after saving the contents of the source file to the new storage location).  Simply changing the FileField instances storage doesn't seem to work.

Is this possible without the use of a second FileField model attr which has been told to use a different storage backend?  Ideally I'd like to not have to double up on the fields and put switches in all the templates that reference the files.

Thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't need to "put switches in all the templates that reference the files" if you doubled up the fields - put the logic for determining which field to use in a method on your model, and then call that method in your template.

Comment: There might be no way around having a field for each location, but it feels a little clunky when all I really want to do is tell an instance of my models FileField that its file lives somewhere else now.

Comment: OK, so I've implemented it as a second FileField.. not so bad :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `storage` associated with a `FileField` is not written to the database, so setting it on a particular field instance wouldn't persist. Instead it is read from the `FileField` instance associated with the model (so if you have `file = models.FileField(..., storage=some_storage)` it is reset to `some_storage` every time the models are setup by Django).